# Unknown proprietary Micro-USB variant

Tags: hardware

While reversing a Sena Bluetooth Headset i noticed that the programming port of the internal chip is routed out to 6 additional undocumented Pins inside of the Micro-USB connector. Whats the best method for connecting to that without opening up the headset each time?

[image: Unknown Connector]

Added a sketch of the location of the pins
[image: Paint sketch of the connector]

Addendum: With some lighting around inside i noticed that the connectors are on a step at the back (upper red line shows the location of those 6 pins)
[image: Side view sketch]

Comment: I am sorry but that photo is totally blurred (wrong focus) so that you can't see anything.

Comment: Picture shows 6 extra pins on the top side of a micro-usb connector where there shouldnt be any pins. Photographing that with a phone camera isnt that easy. Going to try to take a better picture in a few hours. (at work atm)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about electronics, so https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like i found it out. They abuse the 11-Pin Samsung MHL Adapter.